# Fast Bluetooth LE discovery on Linux?

Tags: python, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I’m looking to perform Bluetooth LE device discovery on Ubuntu 22.04, coding in Python 3.10.

I’ve got a prototype using the “pybluez” library, and it’s slow. Very slow compared to other solutions on the same machine.

When I run the “Bluetooth Settings” GUI. It’s at least 10x faster than my python prototype.

When I run “bluetoothctl” and “scan le” it’s also much faster than my prototype.

An interesting third case: I run bluetoothctl, and then open the Bluetooth Settings GUI. I can see the GUI’s scan results in the CLI. Very fast! I’m guessing they both use DBus messages, and the CLI decodes messages also received by the GUI.

Another guess - the GUI issues commands on DBus. The bluetoothctl CUI doesn’t report these, though.

I’m guessing that I could use the DBus Python library to do device discovery as the settings GUI does, if I could see what command messages it writes.

How can I log/inspect DBus messages being written by the “Bluetooth Settings” app? Is there an introspection tool for DBus?

I’ve read the bluez DBus API. It’s a bit thin. Are there other examples of apps using bluez via DBus to discover LE devices?

Comment: It's not the best example, but there is a discovery example in the test directory of the BlueZ tree at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-discovery

Comment: Thanks!  looks nice and clean - I'll take a look.